How to use React cloudinary with typescript?

I am working on a project with TypeScript and React.
trying to use react cloudinary to upload an image and get the url for the image.
Since the example code is in js, an error occurs if I create a file with tsx.

This is the example code I would like to use.
`
    import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    // Create a context to manage the script loading state
    const CloudinaryScriptContext = createContext();
    
    function CloudinaryUploadWidget({ uwConfig, setPublicId }) {
      const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Check if the script is already loaded
        if (!loaded) {
          const uwScript = document.getElementById("uw");
          if (!uwScript) {
            // If not loaded, create and load the script
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("async", "");
            script.setAttribute("id", "uw");
            script.src = "https://upload-widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js";
            script.addEventListener("load", () => setLoaded(true));
            document.body.appendChild(script);
          } else {
            // If already loaded, update the state
            setLoaded(true);
          }
        }
      }, [loaded]);
    
      const initializeCloudinaryWidget = () => {
        if (loaded) {
          var myWidget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
            uwConfig,
            (error, result) => {
              if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
                console.log("Done! Here is the image info: ", result.info);
                setPublicId(result.info.public_id);
              }
            }
          );
        
          document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener(
            "click",
            function () {
              myWidget.open();
            },
            false
          );
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <CloudinaryScriptContext.Provider value={{ loaded }}>
          <button
            id="upload_widget"
            className="cloudinary-button"
            onClick={initializeCloudinaryWidget}
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </CloudinaryScriptContext.Provider>
      );
    }
    
    export default CloudinaryUploadWidget;
    export { CloudinaryScriptContext };

`
Example code link => https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_image_and_video_upload

Since I am not going to modify the functional part, I tried to ignore the type using any.

I tried using both const and let instead of var in var myWidget on line 30.

I want to use this code without type errors.

I would like to use CloudinaryUploadWidget.js by changing it to CloudinaryUploadWidget.tsx.


I would appreciate your help.

Try this code;
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Create a context to manage the script loading state
const CloudinaryScriptContext = createContext<{ loaded: boolean }>({ loaded: false });

interface CloudinaryUploadWidgetProps {
  uwConfig: any; // Adjust the type based on the actual type of uwConfig
  setPublicId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | undefined>>;
}

function CloudinaryUploadWidget({ uwConfig, setPublicId }: CloudinaryUploadWidgetProps) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the script is already loaded
    if (!loaded) {
      const uwScript = document.getElementById("uw");
      if (!uwScript) {
        // If not loaded, create and load the script
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("async", "");
        script.setAttribute("id", "uw");
        script.src = "https://upload-widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js";
        script.addEventListener("load", () => setLoaded(true));
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } else {
        // If already loaded, update the state
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  const initializeCloudinaryWidget = () => {
    if (loaded) {
      const myWidget: any = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
        uwConfig,
        (error: any, result: any) => {
          if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
            console.log("Done! Here is the image info: ", result.info);
            setPublicId(result.info.public_id);
          }
        }
      );

      document.getElementById("upload_widget")?.addEventListener(
        "click",
        () => {
          myWidget.open();
        },
        false
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <CloudinaryScriptContext.Provider value={{ loaded }}>
      <button
        id="upload_widget"
        className="cloudinary-button"
        onClick={initializeCloudinaryWidget}
      >
        Upload
      </button>
    </CloudinaryScriptContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default CloudinaryUploadWidget;
export { CloudinaryScriptContext };


